# How do you bind to dynamic content in wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf, dynamic, binding

My Situation put simply is that if i have a textbox, lets call it A.
when i update the value in this text box it should update a label - B.
when B changes then it should update another label C.

so, effectively i wish to emply binding in the form of C bind to B which binds to A.

i have tried the following but C never gets updated.

```
    <TextBox Grid.Row="0" Name="A"/>        
    <Label Grid.Row="1" Name="B" Content="{Binding Text, ElementName=A, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
    <Label Grid.Row="2" Name="C" Content="{Binding Text, ElementName=B}"/>
```

Comment: Run your application in DEBUG mode and look at the visual studio output panel before asking questions !! I'm sure that a DataBinding Error is raised because property "Text" was not found in element B !

Answer (score 2):

Try it like this:

```
<TextBox Grid.Row="0" Name="A"/>
<Label Grid.Row="1" Name="B" Content="{Binding Text, ElementName=A}"/>
<Label Grid.Row="2" Name="C" Content="{Binding Content, ElementName=B}"/>
```

You have to bind to the Content property.